# NodeJS use the request module get a url that contains chinese

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use a RESTful API that looks like `https://example.com/book/search/q?={bookName}`. I use the node module `request` analog POST request. When the `bookName` is full english, it works well. But when the `bookName` contains chinese, it dosen't work. Here is my code:

```
request({
    uri: 'https://example.com/book/search?q=' + bookName,
    method: 'GET'
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
        Do something ...
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to encode the name. Use

```
uri: 'https://example.com/book/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(bookName),
```

Comment: Thank you very muck, it works. Begin to learn node, actuall forget the JS's function. =. =